# Evaluating boolean expressions and annotating the result

Tags: python, django, postgresql

Let's say I have a model:

```
class Measurement(models.Model):
    measurements = JSONField(
        null=True, blank=True, help_text="Key value pairs for measurements."
    )

    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    class Meta:
        get_latest_by = "timestamp"
```

The values within the `measurements` are VARIABLE amounts of key value pairs with boolean values but the values could also be null. For example:

```
{
    "a": true,
    "b": false, // optional
    "c": null // optional
    //etc...can be infinite amount of values.
}
```

I need to be able to AND those together. For example:

`result_expression = F("measurements__a") & F("measurements__b") & F("measurements__c") & F("measurement__...")`

Obviously, this doesn't work.

Also, how would I be able to annotate the results of that?
`Measurement.objects.annotate(result=result_expression).values("result")`

Where the result here should be `False` because of the null and False values.

How would I go about doing this? I'm aware that I can do this purely with Python. I'd rather not do that. If there's a Postgres or Django way to do it, I'd rather do that.

Answer (score 2):

You can check if the three values are `True` with:

```
Measurement.objects.annotate(
    measurements__a=True,
    measurements__b=True,
    measurements__c=True
).values('result')
```

or you can annotate with a [**`Case`** expression [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/conditional-expressions/#case):

```
from django.db.models import BooleanField, Case, Value, When

Measurement.objects.annotate(
    result=Case(
        When(
            measurements__a=True,
            measurements__b=True,
            measurements__c=True,
            value=Value(True)
        ),
        default=Value(False),
        output_field=BooleanField()
    )
).values('result')
```

For a variable number of keys, we can use *dictionary unpacking*:

```
from django.db.models import BooleanField, Case, Value, When

items = ['a', 'b', 'c']

Measurement.objects.annotate(
    result=Case(
        When(
            **{f'measurements__{k}': True for k in items },
            value=Value(True)
        ),
        default=Value(False),
        output_field=BooleanField()
    )
).values('result')
```

Comment: I can't believe I didn't think of this. Thanks!

Comment: Hi.

I now remember why I didn't do this. The key value pairs within the `measurements` field are of variable amount.

Comment: @Mikko: you can use dictionary unpacking to do this, see edit.